# Data Insert в SQL таблицу с помощью PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, база-данных, insert

Итак, есть таблица, сервер, и необходимо вставить данные в эту самую таблицу. Но выходит так, что данные не вставляются и выводит только id. (1; 2). В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" onclick="insert_in_table_by_name()">INSERT Table</button><br>
```

JS:

```
function insert_in_table_by_name(){
    var dataname = prompt("Input DATABASE name to SELECT...", '');
    var table_name = prompt("Input TABLE name to SELECT...", '');

    var pic = prompt("Input PICTURE...", '');
    var titl = prompt("Input TITLE...", '');
    var desc = prompt("Input DESCRIPTION...", '');

    if (dataname == "" 
        || dataname == null 
        || table_name == "" 
        || table_name == null 
        || pic == "" 
        || pic == null 
        || titl == "" 
        || titl == null 
        || desc == "" 
        || desc == null){

        alert("Operation stopped...")
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'functions.php',
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {action: "insert-in-table", 
            basename: dataname, 
            tablename: table_name,
            picture: pic,
            title: titl,
            description: desc},
        success: function(data){
            alert(data)
        }
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == "insert-in-table"){
    $link = mysqli_connect("db.com", "user", "passwd", $_POST['basename']);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();}

    $pic = $_POST['picture'];
    $tit = $_POST['title'];
    $desc = $_POST['description'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $_POST["tablename"] . " (picture, title, description) VALUES ('$pic', '$tit', '$desc')";

    if ($link->query($sql) === TRUE) {
      echo "INSERTED successfully";
    } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $link->error;
    }

    $link->close();
}
```

Comment: Проблема может быть в чем угодно. и не понятно как он вообще может выводить некий id (вы так пишите), если в коде нигде нет выдачи id. Может вы вообще не ту php вызываете или не от туда.

Comment: @Mike   Id получаю из базы данных непосредственно глазами. Увы, только один скрипт php. Новая запись создаётся, как надо, но в ней поля picture, title, description остаются пустыми. Вернее VARCHAR(30). При SELECT * FROM table получаю только заранее прописанные id - INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT (про них и говорил).

Comment: echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $link->error что выводит?

Comment: @fixer   ошибку выводит. Если таковая имеется

Comment: К слову в функцию заходит и даже выводит то, что я в промпте написал. И после Insert всё работает корректно. Может быть ошибка ещё на создании базы данных? Что-нибудь не так ввёл, м?

Comment: Если запись создается, может $_POST[] пустые?

Comment: Нет, проверял $_POST["value"] через echo ($_POST["picture"] . " " . $_POST["title"] . " " . $_POST["description"]); - работает

Comment: вместо `echo "INSERTED successfully";` напишите `echo "INSERTED successfully " . $pic . $tit . $desc;` и скажите всё ли выводится.

Comment: @ArchDemon ```INSERTED successfully my_picmy_titledesc``` тем временем в таблице ничего нет. только автоинкремент ID

Comment: добавьте `echo $sql;` чтобы посмотреть итоговый запрос

Comment: @ArchDemon - почти разобрался. проблема была в выводе данных. не подскажете как это лучше реализовать, и что тут может быть не так? спасибо.

$link = mysqli_connect("db.com", "us", "ps", $_POST['basename']);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
       exit();}

  $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM " . $_POST['tablename']);
   $data = "";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){`
            $data = ($data . $row[0] . ";\n"); 
        }
    $link->close();
    echo $data;

Comment: @ArchDemon проверил на питоне - таблица заполнена и вывод ((1, 'pic', 'title', 'description table'),) в общем то, что надо. очевидно проблема в выводе

Comment: Разобрался. Спасибо